# SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm using **Postgresql** and **PHP 5.3.x with PDO** to access the DB.

I have this the SQL query (stripped down version), with a placeholder for PDO to fill in:

```
INSERT INTO t_articles (a_article_id) VALUES (?) RETURNING a_id
```

I want `a_article_id` to be either a number, like `5`, or else it should be the result of the subquery:

```
((SELECT max(a_article_id) FROM t_articles) + 1)
```

However, PDO says:

```
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "(SELECT max(a_article_id) FROM t_articles) + 1"
```

And I've tried to set the subquery as the default value, but it is not allowed apparently:

```
ERROR:  cannot use sub query in default expression
```

How can I insert the result of this sub query (or what can be done to achieve the same result)?

Comment: As *always*: PostgreSQL version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd have to use INSERT...SELECT for that:

```
insert into t_articles (a_article_id)
select max(a_article_id) + 1
from t_articles
returning id
```

Or if you don't need contiguous values for `a_article_id`, use a [sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) for it:

1. Create a sequence, we'll call it `article_id_sequence`.

   ```
   -- Get the current max(a_article_id)+1 to use instead of FIRST_VAL below
   create sequence article_id_sequence
   start FIRST_VAL
   owned by t_articles.a_article_id;
   ```
2. Set the default value for `t_articles.a_article_id` to `nextval('article_id_sequence')`.

   ```
   alter table t_articles
   alter column a_article_id
   set default nextval('article_id_sequence');
   ```
3. Use the default value when inserting:

   ```
   insert into t_articles (a_article_id)
   values (default)
   returning id;
   ```

Comment: @Erwin: Well, I have learned a thing or two from your answers :)